# how to use this.removeChild during the whole animation as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code:

```
if (flap1.stage)
{
    this.removeChild(flap1); // "bgList.parent" is the same as using "this"
    flap1 = new SimpleButton();
    }
```

in an `MouseEvent.CLICK` event and it works fine, the object(button) disapears as it has to be but if I come to this frame again the object apears again on the stage does someone know how to remove the object from the stage during the whole animation??

this is what my code looks right now:

```
text_flap1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, move_to_top2); // Add the button click

function move_to_top2(e:MouseEvent):void {

this.addChildAt(text_flap1,0);

import gs.*; 
import gs.easing.*;


var myTween:TweenMax = new TweenMax(movieclip1, 0.4, {scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Linear.easeOut});
function reverse(e:MouseEvent):void {

myTween.reverse();}

if (flap1.stage)
{

    this.removeChild(flap1); // "bgList.parent" is the same as using "this"
    flap1 = new SimpleButton();
    gotoAndStop(26)
}}
```

so flap1 dissapears but if I come on this frame later again, flap1 apears again

Comment: Is this.addChild(flup1) being called somewhere else in the animation?

Comment: @bcollins no this.addChild(flap1) is not called

Comment: @bcollins should this be called somewhere in the animation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use contains instead of .stage to check if the child exists:

```
if(this.contains(flup1)) {
    this.removeChild(flup1);
}
```

I'm wondering if your if statement is evaluating false.

1. why do you need to re-instantiate the button?
2. are you sure the THIS is the parent of flup1?

Comment: I put this in an click event so if I put on an object the object flap1 has to dissapear and stay dissapeared, but if I use if(this.contains(flup1)) {
    this.removeChild(flup1);
} flap1 will dis appear before I have clicked the object so it should be something like, if object is clicked than if(this.contains(flup1)) {
    this.removeChild(flup1);
}

Comment: Can you post your entire click handler function in the question?  That may help get you a better answer